# Transparency in parallax scrolling not working

Tags: scroll, transparency

I try to get an info banner with a 50% transparent background on top of a logo, but somehow transparency is not working and I have no clue how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: #00a0e6; /* Dark blue background color */
    }

    .parallax {
      background-image: url('logo.svg'); /* Replace with your logo image */
      /* Set a specific height */
      min-height: 100vh; /* Set to 100% of the viewport height */

      /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain; /* Use contain for the logo to fit within the viewport */
      max-width: 100%;
    }

    .text {
      background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5);
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      height: 100vh; /* Set to 100% of the viewport height */

      /* Make the .text container transparent over the background */
      mix-blend-mode: normal;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="text-content">
      <h1>This website is currently under construction.</h1>
      <p>For the time being, please have a look at the old page <a href="http://www.lartedelcaffe.ch">lartedelcaffe.ch</a></p>
      <p>Mail: <a href="mailto:nicola@coffeespace.ch">Nicola</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use ChatGPT, but it just messed up everything:-/